# Simple Example Subquery Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

T-SQL Query

```
Select * from dbo.User_Users
Where UserID IN (Select UserID from Course_Enrollments)
```

LINQ to Entities alternative of Above Query

```
var innerquery = from en in Course_Enrollments
select en.UserID;

var query = from u in User_Users
where innerquery.Contains(u.UserID)
select u;
```

There are alot of complex subqueries on stackoverflow, i just want to see a simple example of how a simple subquery is done via linq.This is how i done it, however its not good because it sends 2 queries to the database.

Comment: Did you confirm that 2 queries are being sent via a profiler? Generally, the query is not materialized until the IQueryable is enumerated, or something like ToList, or FirstOrDefault is used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer is use the ***"let"*** keyword and generate a sub-query that supports your conditional set for the main entity.

```
var usersEnrolledInCourses = from u in User_Users
                                 let ces = from ce in Course_Enrollments
                                           select ce.UserID
                                 where ces.Contains(u.UserID)
                             select u;
```

This will create an exists block in TSQL similar to

```
SELECT [Extent1].*
   FROM dbo.User_Users AS Extent1
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS [C1]
                     FROM dbo.Course_Enrollements AS Extent2
                     WHERE (Extent2.UserID = Extent1.UserId))
```

It's close to what you've asked for and will generally create the same query plan on SQL Server.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wouldn't do inner sub query when you have other options like join for performance. For each row in Users you'll be executing a full query and then do contain.

Answer (score 0):

```
from u in User_Users
where u.Course_Enrollments.Any()
select u
```

if you have the foreign keys set up. If not you can do this

```
from u in User_Users
join cu in Course_Enrollments on u.UserId equals cu.UserId
select u
```

You also should wrap any of these with `.Distinct()` call

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer will cause EF to wrap the TSQL in an expensive distinct around the query.   I would suggest not doing this especially on larger datasets.

Comment: @GregGrater, I'm not sure how expensive this Distinct will be compared to a sub query for each row in the main query, specially for a larger dataset. Specially after Join which should reduce the records.