# How to change the following sql query to Linq query

Tags: sql, linq

**How to change the following sql query to Linq query**

```
select [like] 
from FacebookLikes 
where FacebookLikeCategoryID in (select FacebookLikeCategoryID 
                                 from FacebookLikeCategories 
                                 where UserID = 18)
```

Comment: May be you refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355004/simple-example-subquery-linq which is already answered

Comment: There is a create explanation on codeproject if you want to learn Linq in a easy way http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136028/Learn-SQL-to-LINQ-Visual-Representation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var inner = from cid in FacebookLikeCategories where cid.UserID = 18 select cid.FacebookLikeCategoryID;
var result = from res in FacebookLikes where inner.Contains(res.UserID) select res.[like];
```