# Use LINQ to load cumulative average into MVC model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Writing a stats web site for church softball team.

I have a SQL view that calculates the batting average per game from stats in a table. I use that view to build a model in MVC called PlayerStats.

I want to create and load data into a model that looks like this:

```
public class BattingAverage
{
    [Key]
    public int stat_id { get; set; }
    public int player_id { get; set; }
    public decimal batting_avg { get; set; }
    public decimal cumulative_batting_avg { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I am doing this:

```
var model = (from s in PlayerStats
            where s.season_id == sid && s.player_id == pid
            orderby s.game_no
            select g).AsEnumerable()
            .Select(b => new BattingAverage
            {
                stat_id = b.stat_id,
                player_id = b.player_id,
                batting_avg = b.batting_avg,
                cumulative_batting_avg = ***[[ WHAT TO DO HERE?? ]]***
            });
```

I don't know how to calculate that cumulative average to load into my model. The end goal is to Json.Encode the model data for use in AmCharts.

UPDATE - I tried this:

```
cumulative_batting_avg = getCumulativeAvg(sid, pid, b.game_no)
```

And my function:

```
public decimal getCumulativeAvg(int season_id, int player_id, int game_no)
    {
        var averages = PlayerStats.Where(g => g.season_id == season_id && g.player_id == player_id && g.game_no <= game_no).ToArray();
        var hits = averages.Select(a => a.Hits).Sum();
        var atbats = averages.Select(a => a.AtBats).Sum();

        if (atbats == 0)
        {
            return 0.0m;    // m suffix for decimal type
        }
        else
        {
            return hits / atbats;
        }
    }
```

This returned a correct average in the first row, but then zeroes for the rest. When I put a break on the return, I see that hits and atbats are properly accumulating inside the function, but for some reason the avg isn't being added to the model. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah basically you want to have a subquery to pull the average across all of the games, is my understanding correct?  You can use the LET keyword so that while the main query is pulling in the context of the current game, the let subquery can pull across all of the games, something like this: [Simple Example Subquery Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355004/simple-example-subquery-linq)

Which might translate to something like:

```
from s in PlayerStats
let cs = context.PlayerStats.Where(i => i.PlayerID == s.PlayerID).Select(i => i.batting_avg).Average()
.
.
select new {
    batting_avg = b.batting_avg, /* for the current game */
    cumulative_batting_avg = cs
}
```

Something like that, though I might be off syntax a little.  With that type of approach, I often worry about performance with LINQ subqueries (you never know what it's going to render) and so you may want to consider using a stored procedure (really depends on how much data you have)

Comment: See my comment to Scott Hannen for clarity.

Comment: If this is entity framework or LINQ to SQL, you can't call a method as it will try to convert it to SQL.  But if LINQ to Objects, sure anything is in play.  I included a second example above as to how you may be able to do that...  If the function returns a list of objects, that can be stored in the cumulative variable and joined like I have in the second example.

Comment: Did you see the update I added to the original question? I got a function call to somewhat work, it seems to be calculating correctly but the values aren't being stored in the model. I don't see a second example added to your comment? Apologies if I seem obtuse, this is all new to me and I am writing this app to learn MVC and C# coming from a classic ASP skillset.

Comment: No worries, and sorry I meant the only example I had (I thought I had another).  Anyway forget that, so could it be because inside that function, the Where clause isn't finding the data for the other players?  So in order for that to work, does PlayerStats have all stats for all games in order to sum that information?  Also, sometimes one of the variables isn't working properly, it may result in a zero calc (like Hits not being returned correctly).  I've done what you had before, and it was usually something with one of my queries.

Comment: I added a break point at the `return hits / atbats;` line and it cycled thru all the players correctly, grabbing accurate values for hits and at bats for each game. So I can't figure out why that value only got stored in the model the first time and every subsequent time it was stored as zero.

Comment: I'm going to investigate using a stored procedure for this. I've used them before, but just not in an MVC C# app. So off to search Google/Stackoverflow to figure out how to do it! If you have any other suggestions why the other method doesn't work or how to fix it, I would love to hear them.

Comment: I don't.  When I experienced this, I found it was often something wasn't loading correctly.... so I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Now from the comments I think I understand what a cumulative batting average is. It sounds like for a given game, it's an average based on the sum of hits and at bats in that game and the previous games.

So let's say that you have a collection of stats that's already filtered by a player and season:

```
var playerSeasonStats = PlayerStats.Where(g => 
    g.season_id == season_id && g.player_id == player_id && g.game_no <= game_no)
    .ToArray();
```

I originally wrote the next part as a Linq expression. But that's just a habit, and in this case it's much simpler and easier to read with a normal `for/each` loop.

```
var playerSeasonStats = PlayerStats as PlayerStat[] ?? PlayerStats;
var averages = new List<BattingAverage>();
int cumulativeHits = 0;
int cumulativeAtBats = 0;
foreach (var stat in playerSeasonStats.OrderBy(stat => stat.game_no))
{
    cumulativeHits += stat.Hits;
    cumulativeAtBats += stat.AtBats;
    var average = new BattingAverage
    {
        player_id = stat.player_id,
        stat_id = stat.stat_id,
        batting_avg = stat.Hits/stat.AtBats,
        cumulative_batting_avg = cumulativeHits/cumulativeAtBats
    };
    averages.Add(average);
}
```

Comment: The cumulative avg would accumulate as the model is built. So if the batter went 3 for 4 in game one (row one of data), his avg would be .750 and cumulative would be .750. Then the second game (second row of data) if he goes 2 for 4 then his avg would be .500 and cumulative would be 5 for 8 or .625

Comment: Can I call a function like
`cumulative_batting_avg = getCumulative(b.hits, b.atbats)`

Is that possible?