# LINQ - Creating Subquery based on Where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm seeing behavior in LINQ that I just don't understand and I really want to prevent it from happening because it's causing my queries to run much slower than they should.

The following C# code produces the results I'm expecting but when I add an additional dynamic filter to it things start to go south.

```
resultChildrenTC = resultChildrenTC.Where(x => x.parentId != 0 && x.clientId == this.clientId);
var me = resultChildrenTC.ToList();
```

Good results from C# above, and what I would expect.

```
...
CASE WHEN (1 = [Extent12].[accept_revisions_ind]) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [C14], 
[Extent4].[client_id] AS [client_id]
FROM            [dbo].[automation_sequence_executions] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[automation_sequence_status] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[automation_sequence_status_id] = [Extent2].[id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[automation_sequences] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[automation_sequence_id] = [Extent3].[id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[project] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[project_id] = [Extent4].[id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[automation_sequence_execution_results] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent1].[id] = [Extent5].[auto_seq_exec_id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[automation_sequence_test_case_status] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent1].[runtime_case_grp_status] = [Extent6].[id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[users] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent1].[executed_by_id] = [Extent7].[id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[users] AS [Extent8] ON [Extent3].[created_by_id] = [Extent8].[id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[users] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent3].[last_modified_by_id] = [Extent9].[id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[machines] AS [Extent10] ON [Extent1].[machine_id] = [Extent10].[id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[execution_sync_queue] AS [Extent11] ON ([Extent1].[id] = [Extent11].[execution_id]) AND (0 = [Extent11].[status])
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[execution_schedule] AS [Extent12] ON [Extent1].[schedule_id] = [Extent12].[id]
WHERE (0 <> (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[parent_group_exec_id] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Extent1].[parent_group_exec_id] END)) AND (1 = [Extent4].[status]) AND ([Extent4].[client_id] = @p__linq__0)',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=0
```

Now once I edit the C# code from above to take in the additional filter things change...

```
resultChildrenTC = resultChildrenTC.Where(x => x.parentId != 0 && x.clientId == this.clientId).Where(filterExpression);
var me = resultChildrenTC.ToList();
```

When this runs LINQ decides to create a subquery.  This is a big deal because later on I need to run an EXISTS on this query and would like to extend on this filter even more but because it's always creating this random subquery it breaks up my filtering which causes poor performance.  What gives and is there a way to turn this off?

```
[Filter1].[client_id1] AS [client_id]
FROM          (SELECT [Extent1].[id] AS [id1], [Extent1].[machine_id] AS [machine_id], [Extent1].[executed_by_id] AS [executed_by_id], [Extent1].[external_test_mgmt_id] AS [external_test_mgmt_id1], [Extent1].[schedule_id] AS [schedule_id], [Extent1].[parent_group_exec_id] AS [parent_group_exec_id], [Extent1].[patriarch_id] AS [patriarch_id], [Extent1].[runtime_case_grp_status] AS [runtime_case_grp_status], [Extent1].[execution_start_time] AS [execution_start_time], [Extent2].[id] AS [id3], [Extent2].[name] AS [name2], [Extent2].[fail_alert_ind] AS [fail_alert_ind], [Extent2].[hold_alert_ind] AS [hold_alert_ind], [Extent2].[complete_ind] AS [complete_ind], [Extent3].[id] AS [id2], [Extent3].[name] AS [name1], [Extent3].[created_by_id] AS [created_by_id], [Extent3].[last_modified_by_id] AS [last_modified_by_id], [Extent3].[case_group_ind] AS [case_group_ind], [Extent4].[name] AS [name3], [Extent4].[client_id] AS [client_id1]
FROM          (SELECT [Extent1].[id] AS [id1], [Extent1].[machine_id] AS [machine_id], [Extent1].[executed_by_id] AS [executed_by_id], [Extent1].[external_test_mgmt_id] AS [external_test_mgmt_id1], [Extent1].[schedule_id] AS [schedule_id], [Extent1].[parent_group_exec_id] AS [parent_group_exec_id], [Extent1].[patriarch_id] AS [patriarch_id], [Extent1].[runtime_case_grp_status] AS [runtime_case_grp_status], [Extent1].[execution_start_time] AS [execution_start_time], [Extent2].[id] AS [id3], [Extent2].[name] AS [name2], [Extent2].[fail_alert_ind] AS [fail_alert_ind], [Extent2].[hold_alert_ind] AS [hold_alert_ind], [Extent2].[complete_ind] AS [complete_ind], [Extent3].[id] AS [id2], [Extent3].[name] AS [name1], [Extent3].[created_by_id] AS [created_by_id], [Extent3].[last_modified_by_id] AS [last_modified_by_id], [Extent3].[case_group_ind] AS [case_group_ind], [Extent4].[name] AS [name3], [Extent4].[client_id] AS [client_id1]
    FROM    [dbo].[automation_sequence_executions] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[automation_sequence_status] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[automation_sequence_status_id] = [Extent2].[id]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[automation_sequences] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[automation_sequence_id] = [Extent3].[id]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[project] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[project_id] = [Extent4].[id]
    WHERE (0 <> (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[parent_group_exec_id] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Extent1].[parent_group_exec_id] END)) AND ([Extent3].[name] LIKE ''%UAT%'') AND (1 = [Extent4].[status]) ) AS [Filter1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[automation_sequence_execution_results] AS [Extent5] ON [Filter1].[id1] = [Extent5].[auto_seq_exec_id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[automation_sequence_test_case_status] AS [Extent6] ON [Filter1].[runtime_case_grp_status] = [Extent6].[id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[users] AS [Extent7] ON [Filter1].[executed_by_id] = [Extent7].[id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[users] AS [Extent8] ON [Filter1].[created_by_id] = [Extent8].[id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[users] AS [Extent9] ON [Filter1].[last_modified_by_id] = [Extent9].[id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[machines] AS [Extent10] ON [Filter1].[machine_id] = [Extent10].[id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[execution_sync_queue] AS [Extent11] ON (0 = [Extent11].[status]) AND ([Filter1].[id1] = [Extent11].[execution_id])
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[execution_schedule] AS [Extent12] ON [Filter1].[schedule_id] = [Extent12].[id]
WHERE [Filter1].[client_id1] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=0
```

**UPDATE - Where clause impact**

This is occurring whenever I perform a LIKE on a string field.  It seems like Contains is creating this odd behavior.

Subquery:

```
resultChildrenTC = resultChildrenTC.Where(x => x.parentId != 0 && x.clientId == this.clientId).Where(x=>x.Name.Contains("wes"));
```

No subquery:

```
resultChildrenTC = resultChildrenTC.Where(x => x.parentId != 0 && x.clientId == this.clientId).Where(x=>x.Name == "wes");
```

---

**UPDATE - Possible reasoning**

I've created a number of tickets that may all be related, which I didn't know at the time.

From what I've learned about LINQ-to-entities it's a mistake to use the included FK in your queries.  A more detailed view into this can be found in the following post:

[LINQ - SQL Script Changing based on JOIN Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48574140/linq-sql-script-changing-based-on-join-order)

Comment: I assume you're using Entity Framework, can you perhaps write the query you would LIKE to see, and maybe someone can tell you how to do that using Entity Framework?

Comment: I suggest try understand converting the simplest subquery in sql to linq from here to the your problem... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355004/simple-example-subquery-linq

Comment: can you show what filter expression you are using]

Comment: you may be hitting the limits of the linq engine. I other words adding more filters before the the linq is interpreted may cause in-intended.
Try running/executing the queries as they first work and then add the filtering to your result set.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know that you would run the same query multi times, you can just cache it somehow to reduce the server's workload.

```
var mycatch = resultChildrenTC.Where(x => x.parentId != 0 && x.clientId == this.clientId).ToList();
var result1 = mycache .Where(filterExpression1)
var result2 = mycache .Where(filterExpression2)
var result3 = mycache .Where(filterExpression2)
```